# Why does filtering the same discrete dataset while choosing different sampling rates yield different results?

Tags: discrete-signals, fourier-transform, sampling, dft

If I have a two-dimensional discrete dataset (one space, one time), and I create subsets of this dataset by "sampling" (although the original dataset isn't continuous) it at different rates, should I expect that the same filter performed on different subsets would produce the same field (although sampled at different times)?

To elaborate, I have a discrete dataset that contains a four-times daily sampled field. If I choose every fourth data point in time after the first, I can get a discrete sub-dataset of a once-daily sampled field, although the fields in the 4x and 1x datasets are still the same at the same time. The filtering method is then as follows:

1. Choose the sampling rate of the discrete dataset
2. Perform an FFT in space and time to get a wavenumber-frequency spectrum
3. Filter the spectrum to retrieve signals propagating only in a certain direction
4. Invert the time and space transforms to get the field propagating in that direction

Now, the field I get with the 4x rate and that with the 1x rate are wildly different - not just a matter of magnitude or phase (that I can tell), they are almost entirely incomparable. However, my expectation is that signals propagating in one direction in the 4x dataset should still propagate in that direction in the 1x dataset given that they are actually the same dataset! All relevant signals are well below the Nyquist frequency, and I have accounted for scaling by the dataset length.

I have confirmed that the 1x (sampled from the 4x dataset) and a native 1x-daily sampled dataset produce similar results, as I would expect - and I have a physical reason for believing both 1x results are correct. The output is much different when I try to employ the entire 4x dataset.

My only guess is that there is an extra need to account for the dimensional frequency spectrum being different between the 4x and 1x datasets, but I also thought that the FFT shouldn't care what the time step is. Is there any mathematical source of the difference, and if so, how can I correct it?

Comment: Welcome to DSP.SE!  Interesting question. How are you achieving `3. Filter the spectrum to retrieve signals propagating only in a certain direction` ?

Comment: @PeterK. In the wavenumber-frequency domain, I identify signals in the first and third quadrants as those propagating in the positive spatial direction, given that the phase speed $c = \omega/k$ is positive; likewise, signals in the second and fourth quadrants are propagating negatively. As a simple filter, I take these quadrants into their own array and populate the other two quadrants with zeroes.

Comment: Clarify me your signal processing chain, please. First you have a data set, say matrix A with time and space dimensions. Next you a) process it directly (4x) or b) resample it by removing 3 of 4 samples (1x). Then you do FFT to achive frequency domain? And next you apply FFT to each frequency-spatial data set to get frequency-wavenumber (or in other words frequency-angular response)? Next you filter signal in this domain and at last perform inverse operations to get frequency/angular filtered signal? Am I right in my assumptions?

Comment: @Serj My initial matrix of data is the 4x data. I may proceed using the data as is, or resample as you say to get 1x data. I do the spatial FFT first, then apply a second FFT to the wavenumber-time data to get signal in the wavenumber-frequency domain. Next is the filter as I have described in a previous comment. Following that I apply an inverse FFT in the frequency domain, and lastly the inverse FFT in the wavenumber domain to retrieve the filtered space-time signal. I have done this with both the 1x and 4x data.

Comment: So 1) does your input signal satisfy narrowband condition for the array processing? 2) I suppose the inverse spatial FFT is excess because after the first spatial FFT you have the set of spatially filtered signals, beams. 3) when you resample your signal you increase the signal's bandwidth to sampling frequency ratio by 4 because it is decimation. Maybe it could affect your algorithm performance, especially if your signal is wideband.

Comment: @Serj I'm afraid I don't know what the narrowband condition is. Why is the inverse spatial FFT excess? Do I not need it to return to physical space from wavenumber space?

Comment: The narrowband condition is signal's bandwidth is much less than carrier frequency. For the most of radio systems it could be applied. But for sound/ultrasound systems it isn't valid.

Comment: Sorry, updating.. The narrowband condition is signal's bandwidth is much less than carrier frequency. For the most of radio systems it could be applied. But for sound/ultrasound systems it isn't valid. The goal of the beamforming is to produce beam to achive array gain and suppress interference. When you apply spatial FFT you get a set of beams or transform pure spatial-time or spatial-frequency data to beamspace domain (or wavenumber space). Treat spatial FFT as a bank of spatial filters. If you do inverse one, you lose signal improvement achivied by the direct one.

Comment: @Serj I'm not sure that there is an applicable carrier frequency - I'm applying FFTs to atmospheric data, looking for waveforms in pressure records. We know that waves exist in the atmosphere, and their spectra in both space and time is decidedly red. I am simply trying to isolate those signals propagating east from those propagating west, and to return the filtered signals from spectral space to physical space I have always performed an inverse transform.

Comment: If you mean by same filter as measured by the number of samples used, you actually implement different filters in the time/spatial frequency domain. As the sampling rate is reduced, it is like utilizing a wider filter - if there is a certain "frequency" that is dominant enough in the filtered signal before you might "lose" it with the lower sampling rate - this could result a totally different 2D picture.

Comment: @Soular, I understand you're talking about mechanical phenomenon, right? And the spectrum of interest lies in sound waves frequency range or close to it. So if it is true, you face true wideband signal's model. And you can't apply phase-and-sum beamforming techniques anymore. Instead you have to look at wideband ones, e.g. frequency domain beamformings. These techniques are used in ultrasound imaging and hydroacoustic SONARs.

Comment: @Moti That is true. However, since the spectrum is so red, I have confirmed that it is nowhere near the Nyquist frequency in the original and resampled datasets. In any case, the decimated dataset is the one that's correct!  I should also iterate that I have accounted for the different filtering parameters between datasets. They are different filters, but they perform the same function of splitting the signals by propagation direction, which is what I meant.

Comment: @Serj The spectrum of interest is not near that of sound waves. These are atmospheric waves, gravity waves for example, with frequencies orders of magnitude below sound waves. They are very large and very slow. The dataset I work with is global, and sound waves are not resolvable by a large margin, which is fine for my work.

Comment: Well, your waves of interest lies in the range from say zero to some upper bound well below sound frequencies. Right? So your process is wideband by its nature. Compare wave length of the waves with lower frequency and with higher ones. Your array will response for them in totally different manner. You should try wideband technique and just compare it with your result. Create a model of your array for your band and look at frequency angular response. You see how it vary from low to high.

Comment: @Serj Forgive me, I've never talked about bandwidths when referring to my dataset, so I don't know anything about techniques regarding narrow vs wideband, etc. The extent of my signal processing knowledge is unfortunately FFTs. However, I can speak to the nature of the spectrum and say that there is virtually no signal in wavenumbers above the lowest 10% or so within the domain. I will take your word that the transform will treat large and small wavenumber signals differently, but I consider all relevant wavenumbers small (although the algorithm may not agree).